# Are Korok "Seeds" really just Korok poo?

Tags: video-games, the-legend-of-zelda

In *Breath of the Wild*, the Korok seeds say that they smell bad.

[image: Korko seed - it has a distinct smell]

Info on the reward for finding all 900 below:

> [image: Hestu's gift - it smells pretty bad]

Are these... are these seeds and stuff really just a bunch of Korok poo? Like, has Nintendo confirmed this?

Comment: You should have a spoiler tag around the completion award.

Comment: Since there are almost a thousand of them, many people working towards that feat have not accomplished it. Of the people in my office who play the game, a full third are aiming to get all 900 and have asked for the reward _not_ to be spoiled by the two-thirds who have either finished it or have looked it up.

Comment: Yes, that's the joke. You just collected a whole bunch of poop

Comment: "distinct smell" ≠ "smell[s] bad"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Yes.

Because it was funny.

On December 29th, 2017, game director Hidemaro Fujibayashi gave [an interview to IGN](https://www.ign.com/articles/2017/12/29/why-collecting-900-korok-seeds-in-zelda-breath-of-the-wild-gets-you-a-giant-poop) and stated that they liked the joke.

> Why is poop a reward in *Zelda: Breath of the Wild*? Director Hidemaro Fujibayashi revealed why poop is the prize after collecting all the game's Korok seeds. He told IGN after the game awards, "We just kind of thought it would be funny to make that a big joke." **Fujibayashi then confirmed a fan theory about what the Korok actually are. "It's just the backstory, the kind of hidden kind of thing in the game the whole way is that the Korok seeds are actually Korok poop."** There are about 900 pieces of Korok poop throughout the game.

Comment: "Because poop is funny" has got to be the best answer I've ever seen.

Comment: @JDoe that answer is literally full of crap, though